# When 1st start the application how to make it this page? (ListNearablesActivity.java)

Tags: java, android, ibeacon-android, estimote, android-ibeacon

Good day, I followed the code on github and had trouble changing the page to `ListNearablesActivity.java`
How change it to when start application, the 1st page is `ListNearablesActivity`. Currently, the starting page is `AllDemosActivity.java`. I tried removing the file for `AllDemosActivity.java` but it didn't work for me. By the way I dont't want the page on `AllDemosActivity.java`. I was thinking what can I do to make `ListNearablesActivity.java` as the main page

My current codes:

**AllDemosActivity.java:**

```
 public class AllDemosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.all_demos);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(getTitle());

    findViewById(R.id.nearables_demo_button).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AllDemosActivity.this, ListNearablesActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ListNearablesActivity.EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY, NearablesDemoActivity.class.getName());
    startActivity(intent);
     }
     });
     }
     }
```

**ListNearables.java:**

```
public class ListNearablesActivity extends BaseActivity {
private static final String TAG = ListNearablesActivity.class.getSimpleName();
public static final String EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY = "extrasTargetActivity";
public static final String EXTRAS_NEARABLE = "extrasNearable";
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1234;
private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private NearableListAdapter adapter;
private String scanId;

@Override
protected int getLayoutResId() {
return R.layout.main;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

// Configure device list.
adapter = new NearableListAdapter(this);
ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.device_list);
list.setAdapter(adapter);
list.setOnItemClickListener(createOnItemClickListener());
//Initialize Beacon Manager
beaconManager = new BeaconManager(this);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
beaconManager.disconnect();
super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
super.onStart();

// Check if device supports Bluetooth Low Energy.
if (!beaconManager.hasBluetooth()) {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Device does not have Bluetooth Low Energy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  return;
}

// If Bluetooth is not enabled, let user enable it.
if (!beaconManager.isBluetoothEnabled()) {
  Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
  startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
} else {
  connectToService();
}
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
beaconManager.disconnect();
super.onStop();
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    connectToService();
  } else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Bluetooth not enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    toolbar.setSubtitle("Bluetooth not enabled");
  }
}
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void connectToService() {
toolbar.setSubtitle("Scanning...");
adapter.replaceWith(Collections.<Nearable>emptyList());

 beaconManager.setNearableListener(new BeaconManager.NearableListener() {
  @Override
  public void onNearablesDiscovered(List<Nearable> nearables) {
    toolbar.setSubtitle("Found nearables: " + nearables.size());
    adapter.replaceWith(nearables);
    for (Nearable nearable : nearables) {
      if (nearable.isMoving) {
        try {
          Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY));
          Intent intent = new Intent(ListNearablesActivity.this, clazz);
          intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_NEARABLE, adapter.getItem(nearables.indexOf(nearable)));
          startActivity(intent);
        } //close for try
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
          Log.e(TAG, "Finding class by name failed", e);
        } //close for catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
      }
    }
  } //for override
});  //for beaconManager.setNearable

  beaconManager.connect(new BeaconManager.ServiceReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceReady() {
      scanId = beaconManager.startNearableDiscovery();
    } //for onServiceReady
  }); //for .connect
  } //for private void connectToService

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener createOnItemClickListener() {
return new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {
    if (getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY) != null){
              try {
                Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRAS_TARGET_ACTIVITY));
                Intent intent = new Intent(ListNearablesActivity.this, clazz);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRAS_NEARABLE, adapter.getItem(position));
                startActivity(intent);
              } //close for try
              catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Finding class by name failed", e);
              } //close for catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    } //close for getintent.getStringExtra()
  } //close for public void onitemclick
};   //close for return new adapterview
}  //close for private adapter
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
    <!-- Declaration that this app is usable on phones with Bluetooth Low Energy. -->
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>

    <application
        android:label="Estimote Demos - Detect Motion and Temperature"
        android:theme="@style/EstimoteTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".AllDemosActivity"
            android:label="Select Beacon"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>

        <activity
            android:name=".ListNearablesActivity"
            android:label="Select Beacon"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

        <activity android:name=".NearablesDemoActivity"
            android:label="Nearables Demo"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Actually what do you need. To show the first page when app launces as the ListNearables activity?

Comment: if yes change it in manifest.

Comment: I did make changes to the manifest but it stopped when I clicked onto the nearables(stickers)

Comment: What was the error? could you paste the error log

Comment: I mean I'm able to start the app, but when I clicked onto the icon on nearables,it stopped indicating: Estimote Demos has stopped

Comment: Ok,what is the error log that you are getting in your computer.

Comment: I don't see any error from my computer

Comment: I mean paste the log when app crashes

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Currently you have something like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AllDemosActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListNearablesActivity"/>
```

and you should change it to this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".AllDemosActivity"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".ListNearablesActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Bare in mind that there are probably some additional parameters in your `activity` tags. Keep them.

Comment: Hi, I have tried your method, it shows the page, but once I click onto the nearables(stickers) it stops it says: Unfortunately, Estimote Demos- ...... has stopped

Answer (score 0):

Have you declare your activity in your Android.xml file. If not try it under  tag. And remove the AllDemosActivity declaration from it.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ListNearables"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```